# Any way to list the loaded images in Firebug like in Chrome?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I'm looking for the list of the images loaded in a webpage, but I can find it..

In Chrome I can list the images going to the Inspector > Resources > Frames > Images.

FF 15.0.1 FB 1.10.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in firebug extension. Choose "Net" in toolbar than "images" and after you reload the page you can see all images has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This way can be used to list, as well as save all media files of the page at once

```
Right click -> View Page Info -> Click on "Media" tab
```

You can select an image (or all images) and "Save As"